# python modules on remote machine

Tags: python, rpc

From a python program on host A, I want to be able to call another python program (package)/function on remote machine B (via TCP/ip, ssh tunnels or similar). A and B have different OS (windows/linux).
I want to be able to pass (and get back as returned value) any python (and -even better- numpy) types. The call should look -as much as possible- as a normal python call.

Running via command line args, writting/geting stdin/out (Popen...) is not really what I want (even if I am aware that json can serialize anything...and this can eventually be working). Also the function argument/returned values will be large (MBytes or GBytes)

I am aware this can also be done via client/server and TCP IP sockets, but here again, this requires defining my own protocol and maintaining both sides... This is actually the current implementation which I am trying to replace!

I would like something simpler, a bit like being able to load and run python package on a remote...RPC like...
If a new function is created on the remote, the host should just be able to call it...

I have googled a bit, and I found something called knockout, which was aimed to do just that (importing python module from remote host), but it looked discontinued. if not, I did not find the correct URL... I was also worried about python version mismatch between remote and host...

Any other suggestion or hints?

Comment: what did you try? Did you search modules for `RPC` in Python? How about [pyRPC](https://github.com/justinfx/pyRpc)?

Comment: what do you want to do with data? Do you want to split it on many servers? Maybe you need modules/tools like [PySpark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/index.html) or [Ray](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/cluster/ray-client.html) which sends code and data on servers - so you don't have to define function on server but server has to run PySpar Server or Ray Server.

Comment: Yes I did look at PyRPC... was not convinced...My goal is really to be able to call function elsewhere. does no be to be very fancy. The reason is that the data is collected from a little remote machine (an ARM processor on a Soc), and needs to be processed elsewhere (the caller). I want the caller to be able to ask for the data, or to ask to perform different setup on the Soc. The Python module already exists on the Soc-. Just need to call it from the host...

Comment: as I know modules like `RPC`, `PySpark` need to run server on remote machine to get data and code. The simpler method can be to use SSH connection to upload file with code `script.py`, upload file with data and execute all `python script.py data_file` and later download file with output - it doesn't have to be JSON but `csv` or  text file created by `numpy`. This method doesn't need to run server on remote machine and you don't have to create new function on remote machine because you send it with data. Maybe with tools like [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) it can be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to update that post.
PyRPC is what I am now using. it was a bit overkill given the simplicity of my issue, and error reporting is not as transparent that I'd like it to be, BUT it works over different version of python which turned out to be quite nice in my case